# Waiting For Method Or Running In The Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a piece of code that firstly calls a method that does quite a bit of thumbnail generation so it slows the device down for about a second. I was hoping to run a method that generates a "loading message" before the first method is called and then remove it when the first method is finished.

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"Loading");
    [self generatingThumbnailMessageShow];
    [self loadAllEffects];

}];
```

The problem seems to be that although the "generatingThumbnailMessageShow" method is before the "loadAllEffects" method it still seems to get called after the "loadAllEffects" message is finished. What is the best method to call the "loadAllEffects" method only when the first method is finished?

Comment: does the `generatingThumbnailMessageShow` run on different thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `[self loadAllEffects]` runs on the main thread and blocks the UI. Changes to the UI become only visible after program control has returns to the main runloop.

You have to move the execution of `[self generatingThumbnailMessageShow];` to a background thread, something like

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"Loading");
    // Show "loading" message (must be done on main thread)
    [self generatingThumbnailMessageShow];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // perform long running task on background thread
        [self loadAllEffects];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Hide "loading" message (must be done on main thread again).
            [self generatingThumbnailMessageHide];
        })
    })

}];
```

Comment: Hi, that has worked perfectly thanks for the help. I will accept the answer.